# Is there a Gemfile equivalent of `^version` in package.json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

It seems that package.json for NodeJS has

```
^1.2.3
```

and that means "give me the highest version, but backward compatible version", and that usually is what we need.  In `Gemfile`, it is similar to

```
~> 1.2
```

except if we need to enforce at least `1.2.3` (say, to include a bug fix), then we need to

```
"~> 1.2", ">= 1.2.3"
```

is there an equivalent shorter form that is similar to `^1.2.3`?

Comment: '~> 1.2.3' is identical to '>= 1.2.3' and '< 1.3.'.

Comment: If you do `'~> 1.2.3.4'` It will give you the newest version of `1.2.3.x` but not `1.2.4.x`